# Strange javafx app look on android

Tags: android, gradle, javafx, gluon, javafxports

I've got a problem with my javafx ported app on android.
After first launch it looks like that:

[image]

But when i go to home screen and then rejoin to application it looks as it should be.

[image]

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
         mavenCentral()
        maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
      url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.1.1'

    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'pl.siemaeniu500.wszywka.main.Main'
ext.CHARM_DOWN_VERSION = "2.0.1"

dependencies {
    compile "com.gluonhq:charm-down-common:2.0.1"
    //compile 'com.gluonhq:charm-glisten:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:2.1.1'
    compile files('D:/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar', 'C:/Users/Kamil/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WszywkaSounds/jfxdvk-8.60.8.jar')
    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-android:2.1.1'
    iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-ios:2.1.1'
    desktopRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-desktop:2.1.1'
    desktopCompile 'com.github.sarxos:webcam-capture:0.3.10'
}

jfxmobile {



    downConfig {
        version = '3.0.0'
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }

    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        //compileSdkVersion 24
        //buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
        androidSdk = 'D:/Android/Sdk'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

main application class:

```
package pl.siemaeniu500.wszywka.main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



/**
 *
 * @author Kamil
 */


public class Main extends Application {





    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Rectangle2D visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXML.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, visualBounds.getWidth(), visualBounds.getHeight());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setMaximized(true);
        //new FXMLController().initialize();
        stage.show();
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

What can cause that?

Comment: Without your code how can we tell? Post at least your `build.gradle` script, and at least how are you creating the scene/stage on the Application class.

Comment: Your build needs some cleanup... Most of the dependencies are not required at all. Basically you'll need just the last one only. Apart from that, can you remove `stage.setMaximized(true);` and try again?

Comment: Yes it helped, thanks :)

Comment: Ok, I'll post it as an answer so it can be useful to others as well

Answer (score 1):

When you set the scene size:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root, visualBounds.getWidth(), visualBounds.getHeight());
```

you are already taking the whole screen on your device, so you don't need to set this:

```
stage.setMaximized(true);
```

Removing that line should fix the issue.

As for the build script, you can simplify the dependencies.

In a first step, remove charm-down-common. If you are not using charm glisten you can remove all charm-* dependencies. If you use it, you will use the new version 4+ (uncomment the line below).

```
dependencies {
    // compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.0.1'
    compile files('D:/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar', 'C:/Users/Kamil/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WszywkaSounds/jfxdvk-8.60.8.jar')
    desktopCompile 'com.github.sarxos:webcam-capture:0.3.10'
}
```

As for the android and jfxdvk jars, those shouldn't be there. The plugin will manage that for you.

```
dependencies {
    // compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.0.1'
    desktopCompile 'com.github.sarxos:webcam-capture:0.3.10'
}
```

Reload the project (Project root, right click, `Reload Project`):

[image]

and you will see them under Dependencies -> Compile for Android:

[image]

Comment: Yup, but when i remove "compile files('D:/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar', 'C:/Users/Kamil Documents/NetBeansProjects/WszywkaSounds/jfxdvk-8.60.8.jar')" I cant' use androoid and javafxports packages in my java code

Comment: What do you see under Dependencies -> Compile for Android?

Comment: Android and jfxdvk jars appear at compile for Main as well. After making any change in the gradle script you need to `Reload the project` (see edited answer).

Comment: Yup, but there is the error that packages doesn't exist http://pastebin.com/xTb6r7sj

Comment: Are you adding Android content to the main package?? You need to add it to the Android package.

Comment: Add it to the android package ? How ;p ?

Comment: The main project (`Source Packages [Java]`) is shared by all the platforms (i.e. desktop and android) so it shouldn't contain any platform specific code. Platform specific code should be added only to its platform package. So your android code has to go to `Android/Java Packages`.

Comment: @JoséPereda I'm having the same problem regarding the android.jar and jfxdvk ever since I'm using the Eclipse Gluon Plugin. I've updated the Plugin to the latest version, AndroidSdk root is set and Android content is added to the Android package.

Comment: Edit: it's only the android.jar which is missing

Comment: @jns I've filed an issue on this, thanks for reporting. On NetBeans/IntelliJ this is not a problem, only on Eclipse. The OP's issue was different as he was trying to add android code in the main package.